# Windows Forms webbrowser - Cache C#

Tags: c#, windows, forms, caching, web

Can I save data in cache using `Windows Forms webbrowser`?

If yes, how can I do it with `c#`?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: The WebBrowser pretty much embeds IE; I'd be surprised if caching functionality isn't built-in...  (i.e. it does it automatically, probably without exposing any API for it to C#)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options here. You may want to take a look at [Enterprise Library Caching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649093.aspx). This is done by adding a reference to `System.Runtime.Caching`.

Example:

```
using System.Runtime.Caching;

MemoryCache cache;
object o;
object w; //service result

cache = new MemoryCache("yourCache");

o = cache.Get("MyCacheItem");
```

If you're using anything older than C# 2.0, I encourage you to look at `System.Web.Caching`. However, this requires the shipment of `System.Web` as a dependency.